# map iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am getting compile error "map/set" iterator not dereferencable". What is going on here?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<int, int> m;
    map<int, int>::iterator itr=m.begin();

    itr->first = 0;
    itr->second = 0;

    cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: empty `map`. Moreover, `key` is not modifiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is empty, so `m.begin()` is equal to the past-the-end iterator and is therefore invalid.

You first have to [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) elements somehow (you can also do that implicitly by using [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)) to make it useful.

Also, you cannot modify the key of an element like this. You would have to remove ([`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase)) the element from the map and insert a new one with the new key.

Here's an example about that:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<int, int> m;

    // insert element by map::insert
    m.insert(make_pair(3, 3));

    // insert element by map::operator[]
    m[5] = 5;

    std::cout << "increased values by one" << std::endl;
    for(map<int, int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->second += 1;
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    // replace an element:        
    map<int, int>::iterator thing = m.find(3);
    int value = thing->second;
    m.erase(thing);
    m[4] = value;

    std::cout << "replaced an element and inserted with different key" << std::endl;
    for(map<int, int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `map`'s empty! What your iterator is pointing to is undefined.

What you wanted to do is

```
int main(){
    map<int, int> m;
    m[0] = 0;
    map<int, int>::iterator itr=m.begin();

    cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have not assign any value. and you can not change the key of `itr->first` of it. It can be read only. But you can edit `itr->second`.

```
map<int, int> m;
    m[10]=0;
    map<int, int>::iterator itr=m.begin();


      itr->second=10;
    cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second;
```